# Serve React app and backend server from same domain

Tags: reactjs, http, cors, preflight

I have a react app serving from "https://www.domain1.com" and the backend is served on a different domain "https://www.domain2.com". Api requests made from domain1.com to domain2.com are not simple HTTP requests since we are adding an Authorization header in all the requests. This leads to CORS OPTIONS request being made further increasing the latency of the app by a heavy margin.
1. Is there any way I can merge the 2 domains ?
2. Can I avoid CORS OPTIONS preflight requests for these non-simple HTTP requests if I keep the domains separate ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can avoid CORS Policy option in your backend side not in your frontend. Where the API is developed, CORS Policy must be allowed there. After allowing you can call API which is serving from other domain.

Comment: I have already allowed CORS requests on the backend. My actual question was how we can avoid an additional OPTIONS call for each HTTP request made to the backend since the domains are different. Finally I solved it by merging the 2 domains to be served from a single server. Thanks for your info :)